# WGL/OpenGL functions acting inconsistently when used with Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer

Tags: c#, opengl, pinvoke

I am writing some basic OpenGL3 code in C# with a lot of (horrible) pinvokes. OpenGL3 requires certain extension functions (such as wglCreateContextAttribsARB) to be loaded into an IntPtr via OpenGL32.wglGetProcAddress. To get these working in C#, I then need to convert the function pointer to a delegate using Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer.

I want to save the functions which I've loaded (because some of them get used regularly), and have attempted to do this by keeping copies of the delegates (I'm also storing the IntPtrs just in case they get garbage collected).

However, on some computers (not consistently, sometimes running from Visual Studio works but running the .exe doesn't...), wglCreateContextAttribsARB is returning IntPtr.Zero when saved in this way. However, if when I call the functions, I convert the function pointers to delegates using Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer during each call, it works fine...

Why is this, and is there an overhead for doing the conversion during every call? Remember some of these calls are used during render calls, which might have many operations (one per primitive).

Render Context Creation Code:

```
int[] attribs = { (int)ArbCreateContext.MajorVersion, major, (int)ArbCreateContext.MinorVersion, minor, (int)ArbCreateContext.ContextFlags, 0 };

//create temp context to be able to call wglGetProcAddress
IntPtr tempContext = OpenGL32.wglCreateContext(DeviceContext);
if (tempContext == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new Exception("tempContext failed to create.");
if (!OpenGL32.wglMakeCurrent(DeviceContext, tempContext))
    throw new Exception("wglMakeCurrent Failed");

OpenGL32.LoadWGLExtensions();

RenderContext = OpenGL32.wglCreateContextAttribsARB(DeviceContext, IntPtr.Zero, attribs);
if (RenderContext == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new HaighException("Something went wrong with wglCreateContextAttribsARB: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

Code where calling wglCreateContextAttribsARB in above code sometimes results in the last Exception:

```
private static Dictionary<string, IntPtr> _entryPoints = new Dictionary<string, IntPtr>(); 

private delegate IntPtr DEL_wglCreateContextAttribsARB(IntPtr hDc, IntPtr sharedContext, int[] attribList);
private static DEL_wglCreateContextAttribsARB _wglCreateContextAttribsARB;

public static void LoadWGLExtensions()
{
    IntPtr procAddress;
    //get the handle to the WGL extension function pointer we need
    procAddress = OpenGL32.wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
    if (procAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new Exception("something went wrong with wglGetProcAddress");
    //convert intptr to delegate and save the function
    _wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (DEL_wglCreateContextAttribsARB)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procAddress, typeof(DEL_wglCreateContextAttribsARB));
    //store the IntPtr just in case...
    _entryPoints.Add("wglCreateContextAttribsARB", procAddress);
}

public static IntPtr wglCreateContextAttribsARB(IntPtr hDc, IntPtr sharedContext, int[] attribList)
{
    return _wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDc, sharedContext, attribList);
}
```

Code where calling wglCreateContextAttribsARB always works:

```
private static Dictionary<string, IntPtr> _entryPoints = new Dictionary<string, IntPtr>(); 

private delegate IntPtr DEL_wglCreateContextAttribsARB(IntPtr hDc, IntPtr sharedContext, int[] attribList);

public static void LoadWGLExtensions()
{
    IntPtr procAddress;
    //get the handle to the WGL extension function pointer we need
    procAddress = OpenGL32.wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
    if (procAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new Exception("something went wrong with wglGetProcAddress");
    //convert intptr to delegate and save the function
    _wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (DEL_wglCreateContextAttribsARB)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procAddress, typeof(DEL_wglCreateContextAttribsARB));
    //store the IntPtr just in case...
    _entryPoints.Add("wglCreateContextAttribsARB", procAddress);
}

public static IntPtr wglCreateContextAttribsARB(IntPtr hDc, IntPtr sharedContext, int[] attribList)
{
    return ((DEL_wglCreateContextAttribsARB)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(_entryPoints["wglCreateContextAttribsARB"], typeof(DEL_wglCreateContextAttribsARB)))(hDc, sharedContext, attribList);
}
```

Comment: "not working" is not an appropriate problem description.  Just don't do this yourself.  Use one of the [many available wrappers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Language_bindings#C.23).

Comment: Not working means IntPtr.Zero is returned by wglCreateContextAttribsARB on some machines.

Answer (score 1):

Function pointers obtained with `wglGetProcAddress` are tied to the respective OpenGL context. So when you store the pointers, you must store them alongside which OpenGL context they were obtained from. Essentially you need a dictionary that maps from a pair `(HGLRC, string) → function pointer`.

Calling a OpenGL function pointer without the respective OpenGL context being active causes undefined behaviour in WGL.

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite it... I'm calling LoadWGLExtensions() from a temporary context which is active, then immediately calling wglCreateContextAttribsARB (without changing active context). The first chunk of code above returns IntPtr.Zero sometimes. You've given me some useful intel which is I shouldn't be storing these functions without a link to a render context if I want to use them again later, but that doesn't seem to be driving this error. I added my Render Context creation code above.